# How to flip multiple views at once?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I am using `transitionFromView` with `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft`. Now I need  to combine number of such transitions in the way so I know the completion of whole transformation.

What is the best way to do that? Can I use something like `animateWithDuration`, then put multiple `transitionFromView` in animations block? If yes, then would duration params of both messages interfere with each other? What would mean each of those duration param in that case?

Is there better way to flip multiple views with completion block for all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`CATransaction`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to do this easily.

First, add the QuartzCore framework to your target, if you haven't already.

Next, add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to the top of your `.m` file, if you haven't already.

Execute `[CATransaction begin]` before the statements that create your transitions.  Then set the completion block for the new transaction.  Next, create the animations.  Finally, commit the transaction.  Here's an example:

```
- (IBAction)flipButtonWasTapped:(id)sender {
    [CATransaction begin]; {
        [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"all animations complete!");
        }];
        [UIView transitionFromView:self.topFrontLabel
            toView:self.topBackLabel duration:1
            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
            completion:nil];
        [UIView transitionFromView:self.bottomFrontLabel
            toView:self.bottomBackLabel duration:1.5
            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
            completion:nil];
    } [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Note that you must set the completion block **before** you create any animations.  The completion block only waits for animations that are added **after** it is set.

Note also that all methods of `CATransaction` are class messages.  You don't get an object representing the transaction.

Comment: In order to adopt my code to this, I guess I can safely have all kind of code between `begin` and `end` messages, but only those intended to perform view animations will be stacked and executed later, right?

Comment: Only the actual performance of the animations will be deferred.

Comment: Oh, you mean all the code between is stacked then checked during  CATransaction animation anyway, no matter if it's animation message or what?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean.  Why do you think I meant that?

Comment: That's the only thing I could come up which could defer animation. If my code, not related to actual animation will along with the animation, it may affect animation performance. If only animation messages are "captured", then I don't see why performance should be deferred.

Comment: `UIView` creates animation objects (for example, instances of [`CABasicAnimation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CABasicAnimation) or [`CATransition`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransition_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CATransition)) representing the animations you have requested.  When you commit the transaction, Core Animation sends those objects to the window server to be performed.